# Manipulate with data returned by stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, hana

I have stored procedure in SAP HANA (let's call it `testProcedure`)  which returns data (for example `col1 | col2 | col3`). Unfortunately I can't modify this stored procedure.

How can I manipulate (filter it etc.) with these data after procedure execution (currently I execute it with `call testProcedure()`?

I'm looking for something like `select * from testProcedure() where col1 = 'hello'`

Comment: Where are you consuming the result of the stored procedure? Is it inside SAP?

Comment: @mortb It is via SQL queries in SAP HANA Studio - it is only for testing purposes via console, I would like to see only relevant data so I need to filter them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re describing works with a user defined table function, but not with a procedure.
If your procedure uses the default result set, then there’s no way to filter or otherwise process the result set. It will just be returned to HANA studio as is.
If the result set is returned via a output parameter you could assign it to a table variable and apply filters when selecting from that table variable.

Comment: Unfortunately it is without `out` variable. So there is no chance how to filter returned data?

Comment: Nope, default result sets are handed directly to the client app - SAP HANA Studio in this case.